# How to make the background-color of a website transition smoothly with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want the background colors of a website to fade into one another after some time (say, to transition from light blue to light green to light yellow after 15s each). Is there a way I can do this using CSS?

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
    background:lightblue;
    animation:changebg infinite 15s;
}

@keyframes changebg{
    0% {background:lightblue;}
    33% {background:lightgreen;}
    66% {background:lightyellow;}
    100% {background:lightblue;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead

```
body{
   background: lightblue;
   animation: changebg 60s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes changebg{
    0% {background:lightblue;}
    33% {background:lightgreen;}
    66% {background:lightyellow;}
    100% {background:lightblue;}
}
```

If this doesn't work, you can mess around with the timing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
body{
   background: lightblue;
   animation: changebg 60s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes changebg {
    0% { background:lightblue; }
    33% { background:lightgreen; }
    66% { background:lightyellow; }
    100% { background:lightblue; }
}
```

Pretty much the website's background will start at light blue, and when it reaches 33% of 60s (for e.g.) it will change to light green, etc.
And when it reaches 100% at 60s time, the "linear infinite alternate" will make sure it repeats.